# How to hide the datagrid column using jquery

Tags: jquery, datagrid

I have a data grid where i need to hide a column in that grid using jquery. I need to hide Department column conditionally that means if(admin == true) I need to show this column or else I need to hide this column how can I do this

```
var Form = $("#Form1");
$("#Grid_1", Form).html("Loading....");
$("#Grid_1", Form).DataGrid({
  DataUrl: baseApiURL + '/Controller/GetDetails',
  PostData: {
    SP_VA_AUTH_NO: AuthNo
  },
  GridId: "GridDetails",
  Loader: false,
  PageSize: 10,
  Columns: [{
      HeadStyle: "width:55px;",
      Title: "Id",
      ItemKey: "Id",
      ItemNull: "N/A"
    },
    {
      HeadStyle: "width:80px;",
      Title: "Name",
      ItemKey: "Name",
      ItemNull: "N/A"
    },
    {
      HeadStyle: "width:200px;",
      Title: "Salary",
      ItemKey: "Salary",
      ItemNull: "N/A"
    },
    {
      HeadStyle: "width:75px;",
      Title: "Department",
      ItemKey: "Department",
      ItemNull: "N/A"
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is to alter the options object for dataGrid based on your condition:

```js
let options = {
  DataUrl: baseApiURL + '/Controller/GetDetails',
  PostData: {
    SP_VA_AUTH_NO: AuthNo
  },
  GridId: "GridDetails",
  Loader: false,
  PageSize: 10,
  Columns: [{
      HeadStyle: "width:55px;",
      Title: "Id",
      ItemKey: "Id",
      ItemNull: "N/A"
    },
    {
      HeadStyle: "width:80px;",
      Title: "Name",
      ItemKey: "Name",
      ItemNull: "N/A"
    },
    {
      HeadStyle: "width:200px;",
      Title: "Salary",
      ItemKey: "Salary",
      ItemNull: "N/A"
    }
  ] //removed the Departement column in the base options
}
if (admin) {
  options.Columns.push({ //add Column to options object if condition is true
    HeadStyle: "width:75px;",
    Title: "Department",
    ItemKey: "Department",
    ItemNull: "N/A"
  });
}
$("#Grid_1", Form).DataGrid(options);
```